# Call to undefined function do_shortcode in custom shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm creating a custom element for the WPBakery plugin and receiving an error when adding `do_shortcode($content)`.

My element is named `hero.php` and its function is as follows (in WPBakery):

- User selects  hero module from option (`hero_html()`).
- User can then (within the hero module) chose to add a slide (`hero_content_html()`).

Visual:

[image]

A `var_dump($content)` spits out the fields and values, which are correct, but unsure why `do_shortcode` is undefined?

**Below is where the function is called:**

```html
<?php

public function hero_html( $atts, $content = null) {
 $output = 
 $el_class = 
 
 extract( 
  shortcode_atts( 
   array(
    'el_class'     => '',
    'css'      => '',
   ), $atts 
  ) 
 );
 
 static $i = 0;

 $output = '<div id="slickslider-'.$i++.'">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
 
 return $output;

}

public function hero_content_html( $atts, $content = null ) {
 
 $output = 
 $title =

 extract( 
  shortcode_atts( 
   array(
    'title'       => '',
   ), $atts 
  ) 
 );
 

 $output .= '
    <!-- Slide -->
    <div class="heroSlider">';

 $output .= '
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-10">
       '(!empty($title) ? '<h1>' . $title . '</h1>' : "" );'
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
    <!-- Slide -->
   ';
 
 return $output;
  
 }
     
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check for the file wp-load.php whether it's being loaded before this page or not.
For running do_shortcode() ,wp-load.php is required.